# Transform signature with divs to table

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, css-tables

I have a small script that generates signatures for mail, but after testing the same in Outlook, it does not recognize the divs, and some other tags.

I'm breaking my head and I can not simulate this signature on a table.

can you help me? Please!

Signature code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');

#sigCelu{
 position: absolute;
 left: 92px !important;
 top: -1px;
 width: 140px;
}
#new_sign{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    color: #333333 !important;
    display: block;
}

#new_sign img{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#new_sign .barra{
    width: 3px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #004375;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#new_sign .barra2{
    width: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #28aa76;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;

}

#new_sign #info_sign{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#new_sign #info_sign p span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#info_sign img{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    
}

.logos{
    margin-top: -7px;
    position: relative;
}

#info_sign .logos > span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div id="new_sign">
                             <img src="https://i.imgur.com/j4oT9Lz.png" id="sigFoto" alt="logo">
                                <i class="barra"></i>
                                <i class="barra2"></i>
                                    <div id="info_sign">
                                        <h3 id="sigName">Nome Aqui</h3>
                                        <p>
                                            <span id="sigTitle">Texto aqui /</span>
                                            <span id="sigCompany">Texto aqui</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="logos">
                                            <img src="https://caoa.com.br/temp/images/icone-telefone.png" alt="#">
                                            <span id="sigMobile">(11) 0000-0000</span>
                                            <span id="celular2">
                                                      <span id="sigCelu">| (11) 90000-0000</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="logos">
                                        <img src="https://caoa.com.br/temp/images/icone-email.png" alt="#">
                                            <span>
                                                <a id="sigEmail">teuemail</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="logos">
                                        <img src="https://caoa.com.br/temp/images/icone-email-site.png">
                                            <span id="sigWebsite">www.site.com.br</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="logos">
                                        <img src="https://caoa.com.br/temp/images/icone-email-local.png" alt="#">
                                            <span id="sigAddress">Rua, <span id="numero">2822</span>, restante</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                           </div>
```

I can not get familiar with these tables, I believe that because I started right in html5, without messing with tables so much, I've tried several times, consecutive hours working on the code and I do not get a result :(

Comment: Most if not all email client don't recognise standard HTML div structures. You should be using tables. Also there is still a alrge amound of email clients that don't accept google fonts. Your CSS should also be inline.

Comment: Eu estou tentando utilizar tabela para criar essa assinatura, mas não consigo produzir essa assinatura dentro de uma tabela.